# Custom woocommerce add to cart text get_title outside the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this to change the add to cart text in woocommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'ADD TO CART', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

I would like to get_title(); instead of 'ADD TO CART' but I'm out in the dark.

Comment: If you're in the dark, that means that your question is unclear, too: What title do you want to "get_title" for? The title of the product? The title of something else?

Comment: can you tell us which text you want to show instead of "add to cart"?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product title inside hook via,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    return __( $product->title , 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Comment: Fairly certain you're not able / permitted to translate a variable like that.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed. I edited your code just a bit and it worked. See my answer above.

Comment: Now, what if I wanted to also return $product->get_price() and $product->get_title() ?

Comment: You can do that by passing the same in the function: $product->get_price() , $product->get_title()

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $product;
return __( $product->get_title() , 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Now how to return both $product->get_price() and $product->get_title() -- I imagine through an array?